# Is it possible to redirect a post request after modifying the body in a Node (express) server?

Tags: node.js, express, redirect

I know that it is possible to redirect a post request to another url like so:

```
app.post((req, res) => {
   res.redirect(307, 'https://something.com/api/test');
})
```

this will send the body also to something.com/api/test. What I want to do is:

```
app.post((req, res) => {
  req.body.something = 'somevalue'; // this value is not added.
  res.redirect(307, 'https://something.com/api/test');
})
```

Is it possible to modify the body and forward it to the redirect url?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to pass the body to redirected URL bcoz the request will come again from the client to the server. It is not possible to pass information between 2 independent calls coming from the client.

Comment: What content type does your request body have? If it is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you can achieve your goal by returning an auto-submitting HTML form (with status 200 instead of 307).

Answer (score 0):

```
//Use query instead of body
const url = require('url')
app.post('/',(req,res)=>
{
    res.redirect(url.format({
        pathname:'/newUrl',
        query: {
           "email": req.body.email //assigning a value from the body
           "theMissingValue" : "some-value" //manually assigning a value
         }
      }));
})

app.get('/newUrl',(req,res)=>
{
    console.log(req.query.theMissingValue); //prints "some-value"
})
```